# How to convert some multibyte characters into its numeric html entity using PHP?

Tags: php, string, unicode, utf-8, multibyte

Test string:

```
$s = "convert this: ";
$s .= "–, —, †, ‡, •, ≤, ≥, μ, ₪, ©, ® y ™, ⅓, ⅔, ⅛, ⅜, ⅝, ⅞, ™, Ω, ℮, ∑, ⌂, ♀, ♂ ";
$s .= "but, not convert ordinary characters to entities";
```

Comment: But what for? This shouldn't be necessary if the document is properly encoded.

Comment: @Pekka: My problem isn't render the data, my problem is store it. I can't change the db structure nor config fields.

Comment: If your database can't store non-ASCII characters, you need to fix the database, not kludge your data into some ad-hoc encoded format. Keep database strings in raw form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$encoded = mb_convert_encoding($s, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

asssuming your input string is UTF-8, this should encode most everything into numeric entities.

Comment: @Marc B, You great, this is what I am looking for. much helpful

Answer (score 0):

Well [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) doesn't work correctly. Fortunately someone has [posted code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#92105) on the php website that seems to do the translation of multibyte characters properly

Answer (score 0):

I did work on decoding ascii into html coded text (&#xxxx). https://github.com/hellonearthis/ascii2web