# How do I convert arabic letters in htmlentities symbols?

Tags: php, codepages, html-entities

I need convert arabic letters in htmlentities symbols. Codepage: ISO-8859-1.

سك - this is arabic symbol for example.

```
htmlentities("سك")
```

returns:

```
Ø³Ù�
```

How can I get from this symbol the html-entities `&#1587;&#1603;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert some multibyte characters into its numeric html entity using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123638/how-to-convert-some-multibyte-characters-into-its-numeric-html-entity-using-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`htmlentities()` can do only characters that have named entities. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123638/how-to-convert-some-multibyte-characters-into-its-numeric-html-entity-using-php) on how to convert arbitrary characters into numeric entities.

Comment: @Anatoly ah, you want numeric entities, in that case, htmlentities() indeed won't work. I'll delete this answer soon. May I ask what you need entities for in the first place?

Comment: You did't know how i can get the numeric entities? I have multilanguage site in widows-1251, and only numeric entities appear normal

Comment: @Anatoly Hmm, I see. The much better approach would be using UTF-8 as the output encoding - it can display all alphabets properly. If that's not an option, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123638/how-to-convert-some-multibyte-characters-into-its-numeric-html-entity-using-php

Answer (score 3):

You're probably not targeting the correct charset. Try: `htmlentities('سك', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

Answer (score 0):

i'm using a function to make sure there are no html code or  cotation posted by user

```
function cleartext($x1){

    $x1 = str_replace('"','',$x1);
    $x1 = str_replace("'",'',$x1);
    $x1 = htmlentities($x1, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    return $x1;
}

so thank for ( ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) it helped me to find what am looking for
```