# Converting Korean characters into entities

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert Korean characters into unicode/html entities but not having any luck. I use this site: http://www.mylanguages.org/converter.php but want to have something like that in php coding.

```
$text ='한예진';
echo htmlentities($text);
```

Example: `한예진` into `&#54620;&#50696;&#51652;`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. What's wrong with `htmlentities`?

Comment: It isn't converting into `&#54620;&#50696;&#51652;`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert arabic letters in htmlentities symbols?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408572/how-do-i-convert-arabic-letters-in-htmlentities-symbols)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mb_convert_encoding($text, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```