# Why PHP won't convert special language characters, such as in Korean?

Tags: php, encoding

I have strings in different languages, such as Korean, encoded in UTF-8 (the strings).

I am trying to convert them into something like &#number; or &auml; etc. whenever possible, but using this in PHP:

```
   $str = htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

doesn't do that.

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: htmlspecialchars is not designed to convert unicode characters to entities.  IT only translates the following: &' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
'"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
"'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' (or &apos;) only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
'<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
'>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'

Comment: You must make sure all your php files are encoded in UTF-8 and all pages you send contain a html header that indicates UTF-8

Comment: @Superpeanut it is actually not a display problem, I do need to convert it to such encoding for other reasons. The PHP pages are utf8 encoded, but I interface with other things I don't have control over.

Comment: @Lauri thanks. is there a way to convert then all UTF8 characters into their corresponding &amp; code?

Comment: try checking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365583/how-to-get-the-character-from-unicode-code-point-in-php), it's the opposite of what you're asking but searching on these functions might help

Comment: @kloop What about mb_convert_encoding? You could convert them with that i believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mb_convert_encoding` like this:

```
mb_convert_encoding($str, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

As found here: [Converting Korean characters into entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442529/converting-korean-characters-into-entities)

Here's the man page for reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php