# Display all umlauts in browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, special-characters, meta-tags

Say I have text and I have several of the same umlaut e.g. the ü umlaut which is `&uuml`; in html. I am posting text into a form to an article using php fopen fwrite fclose etc.

I want to be able to copy and paste text that contains umlauts into my form without having to replace each umlaut ü, with the html `&uuml;`. **Is there a function in Javascript or php, or meta tag that can automatically change lets say all the umlauts ü into `&uuml;` so that they display correctly?** Right now I'm getting the diamond question mark character replacement for each umlaut.

Comment: How about using UTF-8 encoding throughout your entire software stack? That way you won't need any HTML entities.

Comment: `str_replace("ü", "&uuml;", $string)` ? Or just simple use UTF-8 encoding!

Comment: I've tried UTF-8 encoding, I don't believe it works with umlauts, I'll try the function thanks!

Comment: utf-8 works with umlauts. most likely there is some component in your stack that just can't handle utf8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert some multibyte characters into its numeric html entity using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123638/how-to-convert-some-multibyte-characters-into-its-numeric-html-entity-using-php)

Comment: Found the problem UTF-8 does work! Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a function in Javascript or php, or meta tag that can automatically change lets say all the umlauts `ü` into `&uuml;`

Yes, the [`htmlentities` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) does exactly this. Btw, it makes no sense to attempt such transformations at the client side, so no JS.

> so that they display correctly?

If that is the problem, you should consider using a consistent encoding for (uploading), receiving, storing, and sending the texts.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to switch your stack to UTF8 encoding, there is a native PHP function (`htmlentities`, described [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php)), but sadly none for JS. But you can make use of the `htmlspecialchars` function posted [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars/).

By default, modern browsers auto-detect the websites character encoding, but you can help them out by setting a meta tag. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6080299/1568684) has some more tips on how to set up your stack for utf8.